# Do I need to open ports in Hadoop Cluster for Internal communication?

Tags: hadoop, networking, port, ambari

I have a 15 node Hadoop cluster (Hortonworks Ambari 2.7) where I turned off the  firewall when installing Ambari. The IT team wants to turn the firewall back ON, as it's a security breach for them . However, if I turn firewall ON:

Do I need to enable/open ports for all the services (hive, MR, Ambari, Spark, etc...) or will it work since it operates under the same network?

Is there any way to check, if are those ports open when the firewall is turned ON?

Answer (score 1):

The Hadoop services should be able to communicate with each other within a subnet, but you will need to open firewall ports for any external HDFS clients, YARN ResourceManagers, Hive server, Ambari server, etc. and all other services you've installed.

Hortonworks documentation provides a page of all default ports used for all services

Use `telnet` to do port checks